# Get single object in Django rest framework / Angular2 buggs after login

Tags: django, angular, django-rest-framework

Im building Django + Angular2 project.

I have side bar and need to add `Settings` there, which will route to `/users/{{ user.id }}`, at the moment it works with bug, that when I login, this:

```
<li *ngFor="let user of users"><a routerLink="/users/{{ user.id }}" style="cursor: pointer">Settings</a></li>
```

will not show because `for loop` will not have any data. If I refresh page it will show in sidebar and will work perfect. Main idea is to open settings for authorized user.

This is how I get users:

```
getUsers() {
  let headers = new Headers();
  headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  let authToken = localStorage.getItem('auth_token');
  headers.append('Authorization', `JWT ${authToken}`);

  return this.http
    .get(this.apiURL, { headers })
    .toPromise()
    .then(res => res.json());
}
```

Problem is that I need to use for loop because in django framework I filter objects and  get list of items. Actually I filter them to get only one, user who is logged in at the moment (code from views.py):

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    serializer_class = UserSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = self.request.user
        queryset = User.objects.filter(id=user.id)

        return queryset

    queryset = User.objects.filter(id=None)
```

Is there way to get only one object not list of data to not use `for loop` in angular (maybe that will fix the bug). Or maybe you can explain me and say how to fix that thing, that Settings disappears and shows only after refresh. Actually I think that for sure I use getUsers function in wrong component or wrong way.

My app.component.ts:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.userService
      .getUsers()
      .then(users => this.users = users)
}
```

I don't know for sure where is problem and why after login for loop don't have data, so I don't know what peace of code you need to help me. If need more code just ask.

Comment: Why not use: `User.objects.get(id=user.id)`? This returns only one object...

Comment: @Remi then viewset returns error `'User' object is not iterable`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution, problem was that I used `ngOnInit()` and it loads on first time when user isn't logged in and gives to html empty variable so it can't loop.
At the moment I use `ngDoCheck()` which check if is session.

Example:

```
this.isSession = localStorage.getItem('auth_token');

   if ((this.isSession != null) && (this.i == false)){
      this.userService
      .getUsers()
      .then(users => this.users = users);
       this.i = true;
   }

}
```